# Alternative name for a keyword only parameter "in_"

Tags: python, naming

I have a `find` function that receives a optional keyword only `in_` parameter to narrow the search space. Unfortunately, I had to add the trailing underscore to distinguish it from Python's `in` keyword. I don't want to expose such an oddly named parameter, are there any better names I could use?

English is not my first language, so I am hoping there is a clearly better option. Thanks

Comment: I'd go for @kyle's answer. However there's nothing wrong to use a varied form of `in`, but the better convention in Python (and many languages I believe) is to have the underscore in front `_in`, often used by people who have a preference to distinguish variables under different scopes.

Comment: @woozyking: Convention in Python (according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)) is a trailing underscore.

Comment: @Matthias hmm good to know :) But leading underscore has its definition of 'weak "internal use" indicator', which is what I mean by scopes, loosely speaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `within`.

`find("needle", within="haystack")`